# Unable to free a child of a parent struct

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc

I'm having a weird bug where I can't free() a struct that I malloc()'d RAM for.

I have a struct parent and child, where child is a struct of int. I use malloc() to allocate ram for both the parent and the child structs (where the child struct is malloc() to the size of an array of the child struct). I then use memcpy to copy the array over to the parent struct.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

typedef struct child child_t;
typedef struct parent parent_t;

struct child {
    int item;
};

struct parent {
    child_t *_child;
};

child_t list[] = {
    { .item = 1 },
    { .item = 2 },
    { .item = 3 },
};

int main(void) {
    parent_t *_parent = malloc(sizeof(parent_t));

    _parent->_child = malloc(sizeof(list));
    memcpy(&_parent->_child, &list, sizeof(list));

    free(_parent->_child);
    free(_parent);
    printf("success\n");
    return 1;
}
```

`free(_parent->_child);` just ends up giving me Aborted (core dumped) as an error. I've checked the ram usage, and I can tell that I should be freeing the child, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the `&`s from the `memcpy` statement. `_parent->_child` is already an address, and the array `list[]` will decay to a pointer. The effect of what you are doing is to overwrite the pointer member itself (and other) instead of the memory it is pointing to.

```
memcpy(_parent->_child, list, sizeof(list));
```

That is why you can't

```
free(_parent->_child);
```

because you trashed the pointer you are trying to `free`.

Comment: Ah, so I would only need `&_parent->child` and `&list` if `_parent->child` wasn't a pointer and `list` wasn't an array?

Comment: Well yes, if they were simple types, but with `memcpy` the arguments will almost always be an array, or a pointer, because you don't need `memcpy` for a simple type. A `struct` could be passed to `memcpy` and in that case you would need the `&` because a `struct` can be passed by value. But anyway, you can assign a `struct` value with `=` just like with a simple type.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy(&_parent->_child, &list, sizeof(list));` is the problem.

Try with:

`memcpy(_parent->_child, list, sizeof(list));`

The signature of `memcpy` is:

`void *memcpy(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n)`

and you are passing a pointer to a pointer instead.

This triggers undefined behaviour because your buffers contains trash basically which `free()` can't use.